# Callbacks within forEach()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

When uploading a single image i.e., uploadResults only has one object -the following works fine.

When uploading multiple images it doesn't. The image object gets created correctly in the db but the album object has repeat images. For example, if I upload image1 and image2, album.Images should simply be [image1, image2] but instead it will be [image1, image2, image2]. I believe the issue is the timing of the callbacks within the foreach but can't quite pinpoint the issue..

```
uploadResults.forEach(function(uploadedItem) {
    var image = new Images({
        imageUrl: uploadedItem.url,
    });    
    image.save(function (err, doc) {    
        album.Images.push(doc.id);
        album.save(function(err, doc) {
            //err handling...
        });
     });
 });
```

Comment: Your code seems to be fine..Please post more code.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai I don't want to add in too much noise and I think what I posted is everything that's relevant, but I may be wrong. If some more time goes by and there are no leads, I'll post more of the code, thanks

Comment: definition of Images and album.Images ?

Comment: @softwarenewbie7331 they are mongoDB objects. Didn't want to overly-complicate the question as I don't think it is relevant here, but Album is defined as such: var albumSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    Images: [{type: ObjectId, ref: 'Image'}],
    display: Boolean
});

Comment: `Array.forEach` is blocking, i.e. it is not asynchronous. You need an asynchronous-friendly version of `Array.forEach`, try Node.js 'async' module: http://github.com/caolan/async i.e. `async.each(uploadResults, .., callback)`

Comment: I'm echoing @Alexandru-IonutMihai. Your code looks fine. It should have nothing to do with the async/sync nature of the operation. That may just change the order. Sometimes you may get `[object1, object2]` others you get `[object2, object1]`. The problem is somewhere else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gotten it to work by only running album.save() on the final iteration.

```
uploadResults.forEach(function(uploadedItem, idx, array) {
    var image = new Images({
        imageUrl: uploadedItem.url,
    });    
    image.save(function (err, doc) {    
        album.Images.push(doc.id);
        if (idx === array.length - 1) {
            album.save(function(err, doc) {
                //err handling...
            });
        }
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you saving the album on each iteration? Use Promise (probably need a polyfill for `all`). Use [es6-promise](https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise):

```
const Promise = require('es6-promise').Promise;

let promises = [];
uploadResults.forEach(uploadedItem => {
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let image = new Images({
            imageUrl: uploadedItem.url,
        });   
        image.save((err, doc) => {
            album.Images.push(doc.id);
            // No saving here
        });
    });
    promises.push(promise);
});

Promise
    .all(promises)
    .then(() => {
        album.save((error, doc) => {
            // rest of code
        });
    });
```